# How to make this Header/Content/Footer layout using CSS?

Tags: css

```
 ______________________
|        Header        |
|______________________|
|                      |
|                      |
|        Content       |
|                      |
|                      |
|______________________|
|        Footer        |
|______________________|
```

I would like to make this UI, and each is a div. The header height is 30px. And the footer is 30px. But I don't know the content height. I need to use the user frame to calculate.

The total height should be 100%.

Can I do it in pure CSS?

Comment: Can downvoters explain their downvotes? I don't know CSS, so this looks like a perfectly cromulent question to me.

Comment: I'm sure the downvotes are due to lack of perceived effort on the part of OP, which is totally legit.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question. This is still a pain and not intuitive with CSS.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Using flexbox, this is easy to achieve.

Set the wrapper containing your 3 compartments to `display: flex;` and give it a height of `100%` or `100vh`. The height of the wrapper will fill the entire height, and the `display: flex;` will cause all children of this wrapper which has the appropriate flex-properties (for example `flex:1;`) to be controlled with the flexbox-magic.

Example markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>I'm a 30px tall header</header>
    <main>I'm the main-content filling the void!</main>
    <footer>I'm a 30px tall footer</footer>
</div>
```

And CSS to accompany it:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;

    /* Direction of the items, can be row or column */
    flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
    height: 30px;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Here's that code live on Codepen: http://codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/zxdYjX/left

You can see more flexbox-magic here: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

Or find a well made documentation here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**--[Old answer below]--**

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pKvxN/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Layout</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  header {
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
  }
  footer {
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>I am a header</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a ligula dolor.
    </p>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <h4>I am a footer</h4>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

That works on all modern browsers (FF4+, Chrome, Safari, IE8 and IE9+)

Comment: But how can I do the footer is stick to the screen bottom?

Comment: But when the article become very long, the footer out of the screen, and I need to scroll down....I would like to stick the bottom instead.

Comment: Ted, now there is flexbox which let you do this easier! Check out http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Thomas 1 vh unit equals 1 % of the viewport height.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to to that:

The header and footer are 30px height.

The footer is stuck to the bottom of the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 30px;
}
#footer {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Try it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Usbuw/

Comment: This does not work if the content exceeds the screen height. Then the footer will overlap the content and the content will continue after the footer.

Comment: @acme any explanation why that happens? (my guess it is related to `absolute`)

Comment: @giorgim exactly - absolute positioning doesn't care about the element flow.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Sticky Header and Footer</title>

<style type="text/css">

/* Reset body padding and margins */

body {
    margin:0;

    padding:0;
}

/* Make Header Sticky */

#header_container {

    background:#eee;

    border:1px solid #666;

    height:60px;

    left:0;

    position:fixed;

    width:100%;

    top:0;
}

#header {

    line-height:60px;

    margin:0 auto;

    width:940px;

    text-align:center;
}

/* CSS for the content of page. I am giving top and bottom padding of 80px to make sure the header and footer do not overlap the content.*/

#container {

    margin:0 auto;

    overflow:auto;

    padding:80px 0;

    width:940px;

}

#content {

}

/* Make Footer Sticky */

#footer_container {

    background:#eee;

    border:1px solid #666;

    bottom:0;

    height:60px;

    left:0;

    position:fixed;

    width:100%;
}

#footer {

    line-height:60px;

    margin:0 auto;

    width:940px;

    text-align:center;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
<div id="header_container">

    <div id="header">
        Header Content
    </div>

</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Header -->

<!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">

            content
        <br /><br />
            blah blah blah..
        ...
    </div>

</div>
<!-- END: Page Content -->

<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Footer -->
<div id="footer_container">

    <div id="footer">

        Footer Content

    </div>

</div>

<!-- END: Sticky Footer -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around a while I found a solution that works in >IE7, Chrome, Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/xfXaw/

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrap {
    min-height:100%;

}

#header {
    background: red;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#footer {
    height:50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    background: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with Grid

```
<div class='container'>
 <header>header</header>
 <div>content</div>
 <footer>footer</footer>
</div>


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: You should use `grid-template-rows`

Comment: sure , that's was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code and you can run a snippet to see the result.

```css
html,body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

sidenav{
   border:1px solid black;
   flex: .3;
}

container{
  border:1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}

header{
  border:1px solid black;
  flex:.1;  
  
}

content{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  border:1px solid black;
}

footer{
  border:1px solid black;
  flex:.1;  
}
```

```html
<body>
  

<header >header</header>
<content>
<sidenav>sidenav</sidenav>
<container>container</container>
</content>
<footer>footer</footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

CSS

```
.header{
    height:30px;
}
.Content{
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.Footer{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 30px;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div class="Header">Header</div>
    <div class="Content">Content</div>
    <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. "content" will never have height 100% in this way.

Comment: Look at the date answered. Browsers have changed since 2011.

Comment: Yes, it's not your fault, but it better be warned for those who were to use the code, like me. :)