# HTML footer stick to the bottom of the window

Tags: html, mobile, scroll, sticky-footer

Im writing a web app and trying to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the window. When the content is larger then the window the footer is pushed down. Is there anyway to get it to stick to the bottom of the window and allow the content to scroll??

HTML is...

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes;"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html { 
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .page {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .push {
            padding-bottom: 4em;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -4em;
            height: 4em;
            clear: both;

            background-color: red;
        }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="content">
         <p>content goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>This is the footer block.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123138/how-to-make-this-header-content-footer-layout-using-css/7123189#7123189

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 4em;
    }

    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 4em;
        clear: both;

        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately that has the same effect as what I currently had. Thanks for your input. I am mostly referring to a mobile web app position: absolute; does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in the Main in a Wrapper and use the following:

```
html, body, form
{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -80px;   (-80px will be different for you, usually the same as the footer but negative but mine is different)
}

#footer, .push
{
    height: 60px;   (This is jus the height of MY footer, change this to whatever size your footer is)
}
```