# occupy 100% of the space available for <router-outlet>

Tags: angular

I Am using 3 components:

```
<menu (setAnimal)='setAnimal($event)' ></menu>
 //principalComponent
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

The red border component is called the `PrincipalComponent` (`<router-outlet>`) and this should have the available height that results from removing the space occupied by the header and the footer. How can I make the `PrincipalComponent` encompass the total height of the available space?

[image]

this is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8tgjnk?file=app/principal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
    selector: 'principal',
    template: '<div style="height:100%;border:1px solid red;"> outer- 
     outlet</div>',
     styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
   })

   @Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    template: `<div style='border:1px solid blue; height:100px'>THIS IS THE 
    MENU</div>`,
    styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
  })

 @Component({
  selector: 'footer',
  template: `<div style='border:1px solid green'><h1>THIS IS THE FOOTER 
  </h1> </div>`,
  styles: [`div{position: absolute;bottom: 0;width: 100%;}`]
 })
```

Comment: I dont think you need to it will get automatically adjusted if you set some component inside it

Comment: how??? I dont understand

Comment: the route outlet gets replaced by the modules you specify for the router at runtime and the router will then stretch to contain the modules

Comment: @jonathanHeindl So what should I do? I'm not knowing.

Comment: have a read at this one : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 specifically the AddRoutes

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I still do not understand how this answers my question, I am reading the article, but for now I can not find an answer on how it can help me.

Comment: the router outlet itself is only so the router knows which element to replace it doesnt have any visible properties if you specified routes the default route will be loaded at the start and the router will stretch to the height and with of  the elements within that route

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123138/how-to-make-this-header-content-footer-layout-using-css/19557863

Comment: @GCSDC that question does not use angular, for my case it would work equally?

Comment: Angular is nothing more than a web framework, which at the end, will convert all your code to html/css/javascript, as any other web page. Angular by itself doesn't do anything about style (unless you're using Angular Material). Not sure if this question I pointed to has the exact behaviour you're expecting, but for sure you will be able to achieve it using css.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the router-outlet inside a styled div.

```
<menu (setAnimal)='setAnimal($event)' ></menu>
<div class="principal-container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

styles.scss:

```
.principal-container {
   height: calc(100vh - $footer-height -$header-height);
}
```

Or any other way you want to style those rectangles.

Comment: something like this is what I'm looking for. But I do not have a "style.scss" file and I do not know how to get footer and menu height. Can you give me a hand please? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8tgjnk?file=app/principal.component.ts