# dynamic footer class without passing props and states

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a website using `react` and `react-router-dom` and I encountered a problem.

When I have a footer element that is being rendered on every web page like so:

```
<Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="shop/*" element={<ShopRoutes />} />
            <Route path="cart" element={<CartPage />} />
            <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
</Router>
```

On pages that you need to scroll down for the footer to be displayed at the bottom of the page, you need to add `position: relative;`.

And on pages without the need to scroll down the footer to be displayed at the button you need to add `position: absolute;`.

How do I make it that on every page the style is different depending on the page length?

I can set a `useState` in the `app.jsx` file that will do a conditional class naming to the footer element, and on every page, I will set the state to be true or false:

app.jsx:

```
const [pageBig, setPageBig] = useState(false);
<Router>
        <Routes>
             <Route path="/" element={<HomePage setPageSize={setPageBig}/>} />
                 ..... more routs
             </Routes>
        <Footer pageSize={pageBig}/>
</Router>
```

footer.jsx:

```
<footer className={ props.pageSize ? "big-page" : "small-page"}>
    <p>&copy; Copyright {currentYear}</p>
</footer>
```

for example, if the homePage is a long page I will set the `pageBig` to true and the footer class will change:

```
props.setPageSize(true);
```

I can also do the same with `createContex` but in both solutions, I will need to make sure in every page I set the `bigPage` to be the correct one.

How can I achieve this functonltiy?

Comment: You may be interested in a pure CSS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123138/how-to-make-this-header-content-footer-layout-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a better layout for your whole page to account for this, with just CSS and not rely on JS at all.

Incorporating your components into a structure like the following, utilizing the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color:#eee;
}

.header {
  padding:0.5em;
  background: #303080;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: #308030;
  padding:0.5em;
}

.footer {
  background: #803030;
  padding:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit aut et voluptatibus culpa iste earum fugit enim obcaecati doloremque recusandae, rerum ullam quod consectetur! Iure nulla, perferendis cumque. Id, quas, blanditiis! Facere eaque dolores accusamus
    repudiandae sequi fugiat illo perspiciatis doloribus quo expedita possimus impedit, autem id adipisci voluptate reiciendis molestiae. Possimus facilis consectetur similique saepe ipsum, repellendus iusto ipsa iste quod mollitia distinctio quos ut
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't make it to work right now, it breaks stuff in my project and I can figure out why. In my next project, I will give it a try.

Comment: I just tried it in a new project and it works like a charm thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this solution, creating a custom hook that will check the size of the `root div` relative to the window size this solution was inspired by an answer to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495/16168626).

I used the custom hook that checks the window size from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495/16168626), and created a custom hook that checks the  `root div` hight:

```
function useRootSize () {
  const [rootSize, setRootSize] = useState([0, 0]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function updateRootSize() {
      setRootSize([document.getElementById("root").offsetWidth, document.getElementById("root").offsetHeight]);
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', updateRootSize);
    updateRootSize();
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', updateRootSize);
  }, []);
  return rootSize;
};
```

( I am listing to clicks because I couldn't think of abater event listener, every time you go to a new page you are going to click something to get there)

footer element:

```
const Footer = () => {

    const [windowWidth, windowHight] = useWindowSize();

    const [rootWidth, rootHight] = useRootSize();

    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

    return (
        <footer className={windowHight >= rootHight ? "small-page" : "big-page"}>
            <p>&copy; Copyright {currentYear}</p>
        </footer>
    )
};
```

CSS file:

```
.small-page {

    position: absolute;
    ...morestyles

}

.big-page {

    position: relative;
    ...morestyles

}
```

Now the footer will change the className without passing props or context.

If you have a better solution i would like to hear it :)